# webrtc per to per video chat but only need one side to send video to another

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I read a lot of example about webrtc but I can't understand how to chat video p2p between A and B, but just only need A sends stream video to B using p2p connection, How to do this? 
I have tried to disable video local in B {video : false} but it had error, not working.

**My script**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://simplewebrtc.com/latest-v2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
                // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video

                localVideoEl: 'localVideo',

                // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
                remoteVideosEl: 'remotesVideos',
                // immediately ask for camera access
                autoRequestMedia: true,
                //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
                //https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster/blob/master/README.md
                media: {
                        audio: false,
                        video: {
                            //width: 720,
                            width: {ideal: 640},
                            // height: 1280,
                            height: {ideal: 480},
                            frameRate: {ideal: 15}
                        }
                },
                receiveMedia: {
                    offerToReceiveAudio: 0,
                    offerToReceiveVideo: 1
                }
            });


            // we have to wait until it's ready
            webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () {
                // you can name it anything
                webrtc.joinRoom('zika ghe vl');
            });


        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="remotesVideos"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My example get from here: https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC
So, how to the B(watcher) disable send localVideo of B to A, just A send stream video to B.

Comment: Can you include `javascript` that you tried at Question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On sender side enable video, disable audio. On receiver disable both. 
try below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://simplewebrtc.com/latest-v2.js"></script>
         <button onclick="start(false)">Receive video</button>
          <button onclick="start(true)"">Send video</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function start (e) {

                /**
                    have separate settings to get the trigger form UI
                */
                var videoSettings = {
                            //width: 720,
                            width: {ideal: 640},
                            // height: 1280,
                            height: {ideal: 480},
                            frameRate: {ideal: 15}
                        }
                if(!e) videoSettings = e;
                new SimpleWebRTC({
                // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video

                    localVideoEl: 'localVideo',

                    // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
                    remoteVideosEl: 'remotesVideos',
                    // immediately ask for camera access
                    autoRequestMedia: true,
                    //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
                    //https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster/blob/master/README.md
                    media: {
                            audio: false,
                            video: videoSettings
                    },
                    receiveMedia: {
                        offerToReceiveAudio: 0,
                        offerToReceiveVideo: 1
                    }
                }).on('readyToCall', function () {
                    // you can name it anything
                    this.joinRoom('zika ghe vl');
                });
            }    

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="remotesVideos"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No no, I want to send ONLY video live stream from A to B, just Only one direction from A to B and no need audio. Can you do that? (one to one via p2p connection)

Comment: Thank you very much, so so simple but I couldn't understand before ^^